# Asynchronous servlet not acting asynchronously

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

I have a servlet that takes a request and writes a long response. The response is in a loop that uses Thread.sleep(1000) to simulate a long running operation. I am trying to setup an asynchronous request here, as shown in code. But it is not working. When i invoke several requests to the servlet, they all execute consecutively, not at the same time. What am i doing wrong?

And i though servlets are supposed to be threaded - each request to server causes the container to execute a new thread (or reuse one from the pool).

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/test"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class TestServ extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs){

        rs.setContentType("text/plain");
        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


        AsyncContext asy = rq.startAsync(rq, rs);
        asy.start(new Client(asy));
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable {

    private int counter = 0;
    private AsyncContext asy;

    Client(AsyncContext asy) {
        this.asy = asy;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //run long task here
        try {
            PrintWriter out = asy.getResponse().getWriter();
            while (counter < 5) {

                out.println(counter++ + 1);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally{
            asy.complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your servlet container's thread pool configured?

Comment: How are you generating the requests to your Servlet?

Comment: Mark, XMLHttpRequest - "get".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method **ExecutorService.execute()** to spawn some task in a background thread.

Steps to follow:

- Read some init parameters from web.xml in servlet init() method such as timeout and threadpoolsize

  - timeout parameter is used to set the timeout of Async thread
  - threadpoolsize is used to create a pool of Async threads
- Get AsyncContext by calling HTTP request.startAsync() in doGet() or doPost() method
- Set timeout of AsyncContext
- Attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext such as onComplete(), onTimeout(), onError(), onStartAsync()
- Call ExecutorService.execute() to spawn some task in a background thread

Try this sample code. It might help you.

**AsyncServletTaskProcessor:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public interface AsyncServletTaskProcessor {

    void process(AsyncContext ctx) throws IOException, ServletException;
}
```

**TestServ:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/test" }, asyncSupported = true)
public class TestServ extends HttpServlet  implements AsyncServletTaskProcessor{

    /** The exec. */
    private ExecutorService exec;

    public int CALLBACK_TIMEOUT;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // read callback timeout form web.xml as init parameter
        CALLBACK_TIMEOUT = Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("timeout"));
        // read thread pool size form web.xml as init parameter
        int size = Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("threadpoolsize"));
        exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);

    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {

        rs.setContentType("text/plain");
        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        //AsyncContext asy = rq.startAsync(rq, rs);
        //asy.start(new Client(asy));

        final AsyncContext asy = rq.startAsync();

        // set the timeout
        asy.setTimeout(CALLBACK_TIMEOUT);

        // attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext
        asy.addListener(new AsyncListenerImpl(asy));

        // spawn some task in a background thread
        exec.execute(new AsyncServletTaskRunner(asy, this));
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

    @Override
    public void process(AsyncContext ctx) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //do whatever you want to do as process of each thread
    }
}
```

**AsyncServletTaskRunner:**

```
import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;

public class AsyncServletTaskRunner implements Runnable {

    /** The ctx. */
    private AsyncContext ctx;

    /** The processor. */
    private AsyncServletTaskProcessor processor;

    public AsyncServletTaskRunner() {
        super();
    }

    public AsyncServletTaskRunner(AsyncContext ctx, AsyncServletTaskProcessor processor) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            processor.process(ctx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                // redirect to error page or do whatever is needed
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            ctx.complete();
        }
    }

    public AsyncContext getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void setCtx(AsyncContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

}
```

**AsyncListenerImpl:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.AsyncEvent;
import javax.servlet.AsyncListener;

public class AsyncListenerImpl implements AsyncListener {

    /** The ctx. */
    private AsyncContext ctx;

    public AsyncListenerImpl() {
        super();
    }

    public AsyncListenerImpl(AsyncContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        /** complete() has already been called on the async context, nothing to do */
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        /** timeout has occured in async task... handle it */
        try {
            // redirect to error page or do whatever is needed
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ctx.complete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        /** THIS NEVER GETS CALLED - error has occured in async task... handle it */
        try {
            // redirect to error page or do whatever is needed
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ctx.complete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
        /** async context has started, nothing to do */
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure, You need a ExecutorService to execute the threads. Read some parameters form web.xml such as thread timeout and pool size of threads. AsyncListenerImpl implements AsyncListener interface to handle all the processes of async listener.

Comment: Try to understand it meanwhile I am updating my answer with steps.

Comment: I have mentioned important comments in code itself that's why I have left it for programmer to understand but no worries I will explain it first before digging into code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand the usage of thread factory. But wasn't that the purpose of AsyncContext - to take a request and put it in a separate thread from the servlet's thread where the long running response (blocking operation) would run as must as it wants, while the servlet's thread will be freeded and can respond to other requests?


Obviously i need to a lot more reading on EE. I'm using javaee7 tutorial, but it's a tough cookie for my cupcake. Can you recommend some books?