# GWT Create a sub-process in server side

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

Every RPC in GWT is limited with 1 minute timeout, and this is not configurable.

I am consuming a SYNC METHOD from a third party provider which calls a WEBSERVICE.

Sometimes this METHOD (webservice) hangs for more than 1 minute, and crashes my RPC. The problem is that I cant catch this exception on the server side, which I need to rollback some flags (its a more complicated process this is just for a example)

```
try {

...my code goes here...

MYTHIRDPARTYWS ws = new MYTHIRDPARTYWS()
String RESULT = ws.run;

...my code needs to take action depending of the result...


} catch (Exception e) {

...my code needs to take action depending of the exception...

}
```

I need something like this:

```
try {

...my code goes here...

Process p = new Process() {
MYTHIRDPARTYWS ws = new MYTHIRDPARTYWS()
String RESULT = ws.run;

};

p.setTimeOut(40000);
p.run;

...my code needs to take action depending of the result...


} catch (Exception e) {

...my code needs to take action depending of the exception...

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method **ExecutorService.execute()** to spawn some task in a background thread.

Steps to follow:

- Read some init parameters from `web.xml` in servlet `init()` method such as timeout and threadpoolsize

  - timeout parameter is used to set the timeout of Async thread
  - threadpoolsize is used to create a pool of Async threads
- Get `AsyncContext` by calling HTTP `request.startAsync()` in doGet() or doPost() method
- Set timeout of AsyncContext
- Attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext such as `onComplete()`, `onTimeout()`, `onError()`, `onStartAsync()`
- Call `ExecutorService.execute()` to spawn some task in a background thread

I have already posted the code here [Asynchronous servlet not acting asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180212/asynchronous-servlet-not-acting-asynchronously/22180547#22180547)

Please have look and let me know if there is any confusion. It really works.
You have full control on each life cycle method of sub-process to handle any type of exception.